# Plot generation: stop for-loop if plot already exists

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I'm using python and matplotlib to generate plots from a fairly large database of XY data (~1000 folder and growing). Every folder holds a single CSV file containing XY data that I want to generate a scatter plot of.
Since more data folders are periodically added to the root folder, I want to periodically run my script to keep the plots updated. Unfortunately this script now runs for ~10 minutes and I foresee that it will keep running longer and longer.

I would like to speed up the script by adding something to my code that skips searching the present folder for XY data if a .png file is present in the folder. What should I amend on the code below to reflect that?

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Find files containing XY data
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:/temp\\', topdown=False):
    for name in files:
       #find and check txt file
        if name.startswith('XY') and name.endswith('.txt'):
            # read data and store lines in list
            try:
                posX = list() #list of x-positions
                posY = list() #list of y-positions
                filepath = os.path.join(root, name) 
                fp = open(filepath)
                for line in fp:
                    # make lists from the csv rows
                    content = line.split()
                    posX.append(float(content[0]))
                    posY.append(float(content[1]))                    
                fp.close()
                # prepare a scatter plot
                figure = plt.scatter(posX,posY)
                # save plot as png       
                plt.savefig(root+'plot.png')
                # clear plot data for next for loop iteration
                plt.clf()
```

Update:
using below answer I update the if statement inside the second for loop:

```
#find and check txt file
    if name.startswith('XY') and name.endswith('.txt') and not os.path.isfile(root+'plot.png'):
(...)
    else:
        print('no new data available')
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to translate your original question from English into Python:

```
if name.startswith('XY') and name.endswith('.txt') \
   and not os.path.isfile(root+'plot.png'): ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import os
os.path.isfile(fname)
```

If your plot exists, you know that a file called

```
root + 'plot.png'
```

must be in your current directory.
You can thus add that to your if-sentence:

```
if name.startswith('XY') and name.endswith('.txt') and not os.path.isfile(root + 'plot.png'):
```

If you want to break out of your for-loops use the keyword

```
break
```

Comment: OK that's very clear and it works. Thanks for pointing that out!